# How to retrieve the context.done() message when invoking AWS Lambda functions using the AWS SDK for Java?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am using the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) to invoke some [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) functions that have been uploaded previously. The [invokeAsync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#invokeAsync(com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeAsyncRequest)) method returns an [invokeAsyncResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeAsyncResult.html) object, which seems to include only a very limited set of properties and methods. In particular, the only relevant information contained in the object is the HTTP status code (e.g., `202` for success). There does not seem to be any properties of methods for retrieving the error code or the message that are supplied to the Lambda Node.js `context.done()` method.

As such, there is no way to directly get any "return values" from the Lambda function invocation. I have to let the Lambda handler put an object to S3 to store a JSON representation of the return value and then use the Java SDK code to get the content of the object at the consumer side.

Does anybody know of a way to directly get some meaningful "return values" from the Lambda function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda get context message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893615/aws-lambda-get-context-message)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you can look at the results from the lambda invocation:

```
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response
        if (data.Payload != '{}') {
            var jdata = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
            console.log(jdata.something);
            successCallback(jdata);
        }
        else successCallback(null);
    }
});
```

In your Lambda function, you can have something like this:

```
dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      context.fail(err);
   } else {
      console.log(data);
      context.succeed(data);
   }
}
```

You can also replace context.succeed() by context.done()
    context.succeed(null, data);

In the case I describe, the data.Payload will be a JSON string retrieved from DynamoDB.

Comment: Specifically from Java, you want the (added-after-this-question-was-asked) [AWSLambdaClient.invoke](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#invoke(com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest)) method.

Comment: A warning to any copy/pasters: the `dynamodb.getItem` callback isn't calling `context.fail` and returning, so a failure would get logged, then it would try to log data, then it would call `context.succeed`.